# Replace element in list with element from another list - Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list named `rule.start.` In this list, all elements are equal to an element from another list called `com.empty`. I want the element from `rule.start` to be replaced by the element that comes AFTER the same element from `com.empty`. How would I do this?

`rule.start` looks like this:

`['F', 'L', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'R', 'F', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'L', 'F', 'L', 'G', 'L', 'F', 'L',........]`

`com.empty` looks like this:

`['F', ['fd'], 'G', ['fd'], 'L', ['lt', '60'], 'R', ['rt', '60']]`

I have tried this:

```
wut = 0    
for elem in rule.start:
    v = 1
    for mel in com.empty[::2]:
        if elem == mel:
            rule.start[wut] = com.empty[v]
            print elem
            print mel
            wut +=1
            v += 2
```

But it just replaces all element of rule.start with `['fd']`

In the end, I want to evaluate all elements as commands, that looks like this: `fd(var, scale)`

and this: `rt(var, 60)   # 60 is from the list.`

Comment: What about using a dict `{'F': ['fd'], 'G': ['fd'], 'L': ['lt', '60'], 'R': ['rt', '60']}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this would be much easier to write, and a lot more efficient, if you had a dictionary, mapping keys to values, instead of a list of alternating keys and values. You can do that as a one-liner:

```
mapping = dict(zip(com.empty[::2], com.empty[1::2]))
```

But if you don't understand how that works, you can do this, which you should be able to understand (based on your code).

```
mapping = {}
key = None
for mel in com.empty:
    if key is None:
        key = mel
    else:
        mapping[key] = mel
        key = None
```

Or, even better, if possible, change your code to build a dict instead of a list of alternating values in the first place.

---

Now, once you have this, your loop becomes dead simple, and very hard to get wrong:

```
for wut, elem in enumerate(rule.start):
    rule.start[wut] = mapping.get(elem, elem)
```

I'm using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) so you don't have to keep track of `wut` manually, and I'm using the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method instead of looping over all the keys and values, which is the tricky part that you got lost in.

Or, even more simply:

```
rule.start = [mapping.get(elem, elem) for elem in rule.start]
```

---

But, if you want to know what's wrong with your attempt:

You start off `v = 1`. For each `mel`, you increment `v` by 2 `if elem == mel`. Otherwise, it stays at 1. So, the first time `elem == mel`, you're going to have `v = 1`, so you're going to assign `com.empty[1]` to `rule.start[wut]`. If you move the `v + 2` outside the loop, that will fix this problem.

You also have a similar problem with `wut += 1` being in the wrong place. It should be updated for every `elem`; instead, it's updated for every `elem` and `mel` that match, which could be 0 times or (theoretically) 3 times.

Getting this stuff right is a big source of errors, which is exactly why `enumerate` exists.

Comment: Aha, thank you. I already made a dictionary, but couldn't make it work either. I see what you mean about the values now, I'll read up on enumerate, never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to start by rewriting com.empty as a dict, which is what you really want here.

```
c2 = {key:val for (key, val) in zip (com.empty[0::2], com.empty[1::2])}
```

Then it's pretty easy:

```
rule.start.new = [c2[key] for key in rule.start]
```

of course, this fails if you have a key in rule.start which is not in com.empty - I'll let you dot the i's and cross the t's to make it safe for your use