# Replacing selected elements in a list with the corresponding element from another list, very basic beginning programmer style

Tags: python, list

So this is an assignment being done through the MyProgrammingLab class system. MPL is not a python compiler in the literal sense. As near as I can tell it has a python emulator that it passes the code I submit through, looks at the end result and if it matches what it expects as an answer it says it's good. If it doesn't match it uses some sort of comparison between the code I submit and the code snippets and fragments it will accept as valid, and lists some assortment of differences as "helpful hints" (hints that tend to be wrong anyway). The closest to 'error' messaged I get from it are generally these phases like "The variable X does not contain the proper value." So this is more a question about concept then strict code.

Okay so my assignment is as follows:

> Given that L1 and L2 both refer to lists, write a statement that replaces the elements in L1 from index 5 through (and including) index 8 with all the elements of L2.

I've done the prior exercises in this section dealing with lists.  The only difference here is instead of replacing set values into a given index of a given list, I'm replacing those values with the values found in the corresponding indexes found in another list.

In the immediately prior exercise I had to set the value of the 0-3 indexes to "spam","eggs", and "vikings", which I did by:

```
play_list[0:3] = ["spam","eggs","vikings"]
```

Now I already know this is basically worthless code, its the equivalent of connecting a battery to an LED, seeing the LED light up and saying "This demonstrates electricity". But it at least demonstrates the concept.

So okay, I figure a similar approach:

```
L2[5:9] = L1[5:9]
```

Well... no. I get the response that L2 does not contain the correct values.

So at this point, the question is am I approaching this with the right application? I start with one list (L1), and want to copy the values found in indexes 5-8 to the list (L2) at the same indexes so just set L1[5:9] = L2[5:9]

I've read the question [Replace element in list with element from another list - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643043/replace-element-in-list-with-element-from-another-list-python) and I have no idea what the answer is talking about with the building dictionaries, setting keys, and using enumerate instead of loops. I suspect that is a conversation I will under stand somewhere after this particular class.

Comment: indexes 5 to 8, why L1[5:9] ?

Comment: `L2[5:9] = L1[5:9]` is correct syntax and will replace index 5 through (and including) 8 in `L2` with the corresponding elements of `L1`. This should only fail if either `L1` or `L2` has less than 9 elements.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but if I do L1[5:8] it won't include the value at index 8. In a previous exercise I had to do a +1 to include the value of the last index.

Comment: You are correct @MichaelCividanes. List slicing in python is upper bound exclusive.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose the problem without a concrete example of what failed.  First of all, the assignment will work *only* if "all the elements of L2" is exactly 4 elements.  Also, you have to assign to the correct variable.

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary I know it is, but his prior example ask for index 0 through index 3 and using [0:3] was valid.

Comment: @scharette I can see your confusion. I think he meant 0 to 2 or 1 to 3 as trying to replace 0 to 3 with list[0:3] would not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say  "the assignment will work only if "all the elements of L2" is exactly 4 elements" why would L2 need to be 4 elements in order for the assignment to work?

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary it is actually really confusing but ok thanks!

Comment: @MichaelCividanes: we can't solve your error messages until you post the code producing them.

Comment: @prune, I have posted the code. it's the L2[5:9] = L1[5:9]. Actually the correct answer, according to the MyProgrammingLab turned out to be "L2[5:9] = L1". the "L2 does not contain the correct values" is the closest to an 'error message' I get from MPL. I am aware that such a line of code wouldn't actually do anything, but that's part of the aggravation of this class. I can punch code into IDLE and get good response after good response until my fingers bleed. But if it's not one of the code snippets MPL is looking for it, it's wrong. The challenge is MPL doesn't give much in error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have it backwards.

Based on the statement t replaces the >elements in **L1** from index 5 through (and including) index 8 with all the >elements of **L2**

```
L2[5:9] = L1[5:9]
```

should be

```
L1[5:9] = L2[5:9]
```

However, this is asking you for **all the elements in L2**

I can think of one way to do this, as in.

```
L1[5:9] = L2
```

Comment: well face palm for swapping the list names around. but even with the swapped names it comes back with a "L1 does not contain the correct values"

Comment: @MichaelCividanes check my edit. The problem statement is a little odd but I think this is what you want.

Comment: still saying "L1 does not contain the correct values" Could I use something like del L1[5:9] to erase the values at those indexes and then use an insert to copy the values from the corresponding indexes of L2?

Comment: @MichaelCividanes The thing is, it doesn't seem like it's asking for them at their specific indices. It looks like it's asking for all the values from l2 to be inserted at L1[5], L1[6], etc

Comment: @MichaelCividanes Check my edit again.

Comment: so like L1[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] and L2['a','b','c','d','e'] 
would become: L1[0,1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d','e',9,10,11] ?

Comment: well, it's not saying 'L1 does not contain the correct values" now. Now it saying :
"Solutions for this problem don't generally use i. 
 Solutions for this problem don't generally use in.  
 Solutions for this problem don't generally use range."

Screw it. I'll skip this one and come back to it if I have time before next class. Thanks for the help @Caleb_McCreary

Comment: @MichaelCividanes Give it one more shot with l1[5:9] = l2

Comment: you know what my second submission for this was? L2[5:9] = L1, which was obviously wrong, but for the reason of I swapped the list names, not because of any sort of programming error exactly. That was 39 submissions ago. @Caleb_McCreary, lemme know if you're ever in northern Virginia. I'd like to buy you a beer. Or you know a soda if beer isn't your thing.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes Oh man, I'm sorry about that. I didn't realize how simple it was until just a second ago either but I'm very happy to help. I love a good beer and I'm just a bit south of you so I'll keep that in mind. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The line you wrote does perform the indicated replacement, although that's not quite what you specified:

```
>>> l2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
>>> l2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> l2[5:9] = l1[5:9]
>>> l2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 9, 10]
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Using the example you posts why wouldn't L2[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 9, 10] be the desired end result?

Comment: Because you said that the idea is to assign to L1.

Comment: oh. Okay I follow now. Yeah got that mistake straightened out. Now it MyProgrammingLab says "L1 does not contain the correct values"